# replace a divs contents with the last entry

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with a bunch of list items in it. I just want to remove all the contents inside except for the last list item. Is it possible to use $(this) in reference to a div id without putting it inside some sort of click function? Something like this? (I know its wrong)

```
 $('div[id='+id+']').html($(this).(".list-item:last"));
```

If not, would I need to make a function and then call it?

```
$('div[id='+id+']').function(){
 $(this).html($(".list-item:last"));
}
```

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you include at least a snippets of your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you require, I think:

```
$('#elementId').children().not(':last-child').remove();
```

Demo at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iluyi/2/).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a selector to get the last list item, then remove its siblings. Something like this:

```
$('div li:last-child').siblings().remove();
```

Last child: http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Siblings: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Remove: http://api.jquery.com/remove/